# Bash program wont go into if statement. (complete beginner)

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

Can someone help me correct this code. I don't understand why it will not run my conditional statement. the for loop is supposed to makes sure that the input does not equal any item in the array. if that checks out its suppose to run the last if statement, but it's not.

```
  echo "Enter a Course Number"
  read input
  declare -i testVar=0

  for j in "${courseName[@]}"
  do
      if [$input -eq $j]
      then
        testVar=1
        echo "Course Already Exists"
        sleep 2
      fi
  done

 if [$testVar -eq 0]
  then
    echo "successful"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to respect the whitespace before and after `[`, `]`:

```
if [ $input -eq $j ]

# and

if [ $testVar -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: i got that to work but now if i try to go into the if statement inside the for loop i get an integer expression expected error

Comment: @user2012751 you should edit your question to include what you are trying to achieve and post the rest of your script. What is in `$coureName`?

Answer (score 1):

The [ and  ] have to have spaces around them, treat them like a reserved word, e.g. fi or if.  In bash they are a shell builtin.

Answer (score 0):

@sudo_O is correct, you should include what `courseName` is.

However, it looks to me like you are using the wrong operator to compare `$input` and `$j`.
The `-eq` is an arithmetic operator while the `=` operator is used to compare strings.

Try:

```
if [ "$input" = "$j" ]
```

Comment: No, this is wrong: you need to have whitespace *before* the `[`. Ylou also need whitespace around the `=` -- what you have given will **always** be true because you have passed a single, non-empty argument to the `[` command.